# Android WebView in a ViewSwitcher loadUrl loads once

Tags: android-webview, android-adapter

I have in my ViewSwitcher a `ListView` and a `WebView`.  In my ListView's adapter, I have an onclick listener that writes the clicked url in the list to sharedpreferences.  I'm trying to load that url into the WebView using an `onSharedPreferencesChangedListener`.

This is the code in my adapter:

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        viewSwitcher.showNext();
        Settings.writeSettings(context, "webviewUrl",
                urls.get(position));
    }
});
return convertView;
```

And in the preference listener:

```
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences pref, String key) {
    if (key.equals("webviewUrl")) {
        Log.d("TAG", pref.getString(key, null));
        WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.rss_webview);
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        wv.loadUrl("about:blank");
        wv.loadUrl(pref.getString(key, null));
    }
}
```

This works great except it only works once.  The preference listener code logs the correct urls, and the code executes each time I want it to, but `wv.loadUrl()` method seems to do nothing after the first successful call.  Can anyone explain to me why this is happening and perhaps offer a solution?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by implementing a static ViewHolder on the `WebView` whose reference I needed to keep longer than its views' lifecycle.

```
private static final class WebViewHolder {
    WebView wv;
}

@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences pref, String key) {
    WebViewHolder holder = new WebViewHolder();
    if (key.equals("webviewUrl")) {
        if (wv == null) {
            wv = new WebView(this);
            holder.wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.rss_webview);
            holder.wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            holder.wv.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
            wv.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (WebViewHolder) wv.getTag(); 
        }
        holder.wv.loadUrl("about:blank");
        holder.wv.loadUrl(pref.getString(key, null));
    }
}
```